# (file-name-directory #$): How does Emacs know what #$ is?

Tags: package

I see that a few packages, and `package.el` use `(file-name-directory #$)`.  How does Emacs know what directory `#$` is?  On OSX, that returns `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`.

Excerpt from `cl-lib.el` when installing a package `evil-mc` through the package manager, which goes into `cl-lib-autoloads.el` and then Emacs chokes:

```
;; First line of defense: try to make sure the built-in cl-lib comes earlier in
;; load-path so we never get loaded:
;;;###autoload (let ((d (file-name-directory #$)))
;;;###autoload   (when (member d load-path)
;;;###autoload     (setq load-path (append (remove d load-path) (list d)))))
```

Comment: Can you show an example of its use?

Comment: @Drew -- Thanks, I updated the question with a specific example.  As to `package-autoload-ensure-default-file`, I added `(or (and #$ (file-name-directory #$)) ...)` to avoid an error.  But, I have no control over fixing the entry in `cl-lib.el` that the package manager is installing . . . .

Comment: I also get `Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  file-name-directory(nil)` on macOS from `(file-name-directory #$)`, but only when using `--debug-init`. This is with the emacs-mac port.

Comment: I find that I typically get this error after updating packages, and I can fix it by deleting all elc files (then recompiling them).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `elisp-index-search` <kbd>RET</kbd> `#$` <kbd>RET</kbd> tells us:

```
   Internally, the dynamic loading of documentation strings is
accomplished by writing compiled files with a special Lisp reader
construct, ‘#@COUNT’.  This construct skips the next COUNT characters.
It also uses the ‘#$’ construct, which stands for the name of this file,
as a string.  Do not use these constructs in Lisp source files; they are
not designed to be clear to humans reading the file.
```

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Docs and Compilation`

Comment: Never heard of `elisp-index-search`.  Thank you for teaching me how to fish.